# Reading Internal Xml File in my project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I create "Empty file" (Type of file in Xcode 4.2)
 with extension (.Xml), and i want to read this internal Xml file using xml pareser , How ?

Comment: you want to read empty file....?

Answer (score 2):

May be:

```
 NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"your/file/path"];
 NSXMLParser *parse=[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
```